# How to retrieve score value when parsing JSON from Facebook SDK in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, facebook

I'm trying to extract the score value from a user profile using the Facebook Graph SDK. I can easily set the parameters and retrieve the object from server. But I have trouble getting to the exact specific score value. My app is a game.

This is what I am using, the output of result is further down.

```
let retrieveScores = FBSDKGraphRequest.init(graphPath: "/me/scores", parameters: ["fields": "score"], httpMethod: "GET").start { (connection, result, error) in

        if(error != nil){
            print(error)
            return
        }

        print(result)

        // Need help right here.
        let dict = result as! [String : Any]
        let myArray = (dict["data"] as! NSArray).mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray
}
```

This is what the print statement shows in the debugger output, so what I receive from the server:

```
{
    data =     (
            {
        score = 1230;
        user =             {
            id = 1028084234;
            name = "John Appleseed";
        };
    }
);
}
```

I can't seem to access the score, is this a `Dictionary` inside a `Dictionary`? I have tried a lot of answers so far and none seem to help. And also most of them are in Objective C so that's another anti catalyst.

Also, the last line in my code, where I declare myArray, simply takes the first `{` and `data =` out of the output.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `data` key contains an `Array` of a `Dictionary`. The `score` is actually inside the first object of the `data` Array, so you need to access the first object of the `data` array. It is actually very simple to access `JSON` responses in Swift if you use the native `Array` and `Dictionary`.

```
if let dict = result as? [String : Any], let data = dict["data"] as? [[String : Any]], 
   let firstObj = data.first, let score = firstObj["score"] as? Int {
      print(score)
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked perfectly. Question, what does `[[String : Any]]` mean? What are the 2 brackets used for?

Comment: @return0 Welcome mate :)

Comment: @return0 Here `[String:Any]` with single square brackets it represent dictionary and with double square brackets `[[String:Any]]` it represent as Array of dictionary.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the result safely using something like this. First parse the data dictionary and then get the score value inside it. If the raw json has the score as a string value replace `as? Int` wit `as? String`:

```
if let dataDict = dict["data"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
   if let score = dataDict["score"] as? Int {
    //use score
   }
}
```

Comment: What does it return as score?

Comment: Nothing, it never passes the if statement. Nirav's answer above works fine instead.